# VS Code - No ES6 Intellisense in TypeScript File

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

Can't quite figure out why I'm not getting intellisense for ES6 features in a TypeScript file.

I'm fairly certain it is related to the **lib.d.ts** file that is used in the typescript source files.  For reference this is located in:

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\typescript\server\typescript\lib*

I noticed that the same folder contains **lib.es6.d.ts**.  When going to definition on a method that is defined by the base interface definition files, it points you to **lib.d.ts** and not the es6 version.  The es6 version has all of the interfaces that I need.

That said, even if I include some ES6 methods and force the task runner(which under the hood uses the typescript compiler installed), it doesn't transpile to ES5 like I expected it to.

Maybe my TypeScript compiler version is dated?  Primarily I want these features:

1. Symbol
2. Array.prototype.includes
3. String.prototype.includes

I see these interfaces defined in the es6 typing definition file.  Is there a way to get VSCode to recognize this?  I'm thinking a hacky approach of just including that lib file in my project but I'm trying to avoid that and in the end it still doesn't solve my problem when I transpile to ES5 and get garbage.

Thanks and much love :)

Comment: Ok I got intellisense working, looks like I somehow deleted my tsconfig.json file through some of the mayhem of refactoring.  The only issue remains is the transpilation...ES5 set as the target but String.prototype.includes is not part of ES5....

Comment: There's some good discussion of this here: [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3429)